# Android JSON in AsyncTask errors

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to grab JSON data from google by using asynctask.
But i get a lot of errors I don't know why. I'm new to android development, I was interested in it then quit now back again :P.

and on the button click which executes the asynctask

```
                        new usdjson().execute();
```

this is my Asynctask

```
    private class usdjson extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... urls) {
// I get this from Boolean : The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<URL,Void,JSONObject>.doInBackground(URL[])
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            loadJSON(url);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonData) {
            try {
               String USD = json.getJSONArray("rhs");
//I get this from json. :json cannot be resolved
        }
    }


    public void loadJSON(URL url) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
//I get this from JSONPareser JSONParser cannot be resolved to a type
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
//Void methods cannot return a value
    }
```

sorry for being long

Comment: note that it I should get rhs= 0.645452785 British pounds from the json as a string so I sidplay it in textview

Comment: it is better for you to delete this question(because it shows that you don't know java syntax since those error are compiler time errors) ... problem is with `new usdjson.execute("");` replace it with `new usdjson().execute("");`

Comment: You are returning a `JSONObject`


     `public JSONObject loadJSON(URL url) {`

Comment: use `URL url = new URL(requestUrl);` to get URl from String. and start AsyncTask as `new usdjson.execute(url);`

Comment: I changed it, still I get same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`URL requestUrl = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?GBP";`

you should have

`URL requestUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?GBP");`

**EDIT**

First, change the return type of `doInBackground()` to JSONObject :

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
```

`urls` is an array, so to access the url in it, you have to specify the position :

```
URL url = new URL(urls[0]);    // urls[0] is the URL you passed when calling the .execute method
```

You want to process a JSONObject in `onPostExecute()`, so you have to change the return of  `doInBackground` :

```
JSONObject json = loadJSON(url);
return json;
```

But for the rest, it seems that you just copied/pasted a code and there seems to be a lot of code missing, so it's hard to help you more... You have to change `loadJSON` so it does the processing you want (get the data from the Url, process it and return a JSON Object). I fact, copy the code you put in your other StackOverflow question that you posted a few minutes ago...

Comment: Did you try to execute the AsyncTask doing that : `new usdjson().execute(requestUrl );` ?

Comment: there are still errors in the activity, I can't start the app

Comment: What errors ? The only one you mentionned is "The method execute(URL...) in the type AsyncTask is not applicable for the arguments (String)", which should be solved by my comment above

Comment: check my updated question and the errors are the one commented //

Comment: I edited my answer. But in fact if you just followed what I told you in the other question, it would have been fine...

Comment: i replaced the doinbackground successfuly. but second one urls I get this error The constructor URL(URL) is undefined.

Comment: See the update in the other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537860/getting-value-using-json-nullpointer/18538090#18538090 I didn't try it but it should be close to what you want.

Comment: new url(xx) gives me The constructor URL(URL) is undefined

Comment: Don't forget to accept both my answers if you make it work ;) And you can continue asking questions, I'll be around for an hour or so